# PL/SQL - Duda contar IDS

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

¿Alguna manera de contar únicamente desde el id que haya seleccionado a anteriores?

Quiero decir, si tengo una tabla y selecciono el `id_servicio` 3, que me cuente el 3,2 y 1 (siendo el `id_maquina` el mismo) y que omita los siguientes ids y los anteriores que no sean el mismo `id_maquina`.

Lo estoy intentando con las fechas pero no lo consigo.

Aquí el código que estoy utilizando:

```
SELECT COUNT (id_maquina) INTO num_servicios FROM Servicios 
WHERE id_maquina=(SELECT id_maquina FROM Servicios WHERE id_servicio=ids);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puede que esto te funcione, añade a tu SELECT una segunda condición al WHERE para filtrar por todos los servicios iguales o menores que el ID_SERVICIO (ids) dado.

```
SELECT COUNT (id_maquina) INTO num_servicios
FROM Servicios
WHERE
   id_maquina = (SELECT id_maquina FROM Servicios WHERE id_servicio = :ids)
   AND id_servicio <= :ids;
```